# fancybox 2 remove padding between thumbnails

Tags: dreamweaver, fancybox-2

I'm building a gallery page using Fancybox2 in Dreamweaver and I need to completely remove the padding between thumbnails. Please see my test site here

http://www.creativeclout.co.uk/our_work2.html

I can't see an option in the css anywhere.

Can anyone help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img {
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have no css padding. problem your images. http://www.creativeclout.co.uk/images/thumbs/ourwork_12.jpg
crop white area in images.

Comment: Sorry - I know I've built in padding to the left and right of the images in photoshop however it's specifically below the images that I'm concerned about.
If you  look at this example
http://www.creativeclout.co.uk/our_work.html
You'll see what I mean.

The client wants the gallery to look like a masonry style gallery and so I have to split some images in 2 to achieve this in photoshop.

If you refer to the original page
http://www.creativeclout.co.uk/our_work2.html
You'll see a gap below the first image and the one below that  - this isn't in the image it's been padded somehow.
Any ideas?